# How a signal is transfered with only one connection in a simple circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, signal

I need some explanation to something i experience. 
I use an Arduino (DUE) to create some audio waveforms, and a laptop as an oscilloscope to watch the waveforms (and for programming - powering the Arduino).

I measured the voltage of the mic jack and the multi-meter displayed 3.2 V.

When i connected the signal terminal and the ground of the mic input to the DAC0 (and ground accordingly) of Arduino DUE it burned the DAC0 pin. 
I guess it provided current, beneath the rating the DAC pin allowed. (provided or sinking current?)

After this i use the DAC1, and i connect my earphone to the DAC1 pin and to the ground of the Arduino.

Now if i have connected the earphone to the DAC1 pin and to the ground of Arduino -so to hear the audio- and i also connect only the positive cable of the mic input of the laptop/oscilloscope to the ground of the Arduino I get the signal displayed, so it passes through the mic input with only one cable connected.

So i have 2 questions:

a. why the signal appears in the ground and how it gets transferred to the mic input with only 1 cable connected (and no ground). Is it because as i' m powering the circuit from the laptop a complete circuit is created? Does it works with a common ground?

b. why the mic input of my laptop 
provided or sunk current to the DAC and it fried it? (is it because it provides current to power a mic? Is it because it acts as an amplifier also? Or it provides current anyway just because it "exists" as a circuit?)

Comment: Can you please make your question's title an actual question, or at least make it describe your question(s)? "[Circuit Question]" is not helpful to others when they see your "question" in a list.

Comment: Do you think *this* title is any better?

Comment: BTW, the term is "sink" current, not "suck" it.

Comment: Laptop ground MUST be connected to circuit as well as laptop power if laptop is powering circuit. THINK: how does it otherwise power the circuit?

Answer (score 2):

You probably fried the DAC because the microphone input of a laptop provides a dc voltage source to properly bias the microphone.

The circuit, laptop side, might look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN2sHL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

mic_in is connected to the laptop sound card, jack_in is where you hooked the DAC, Vdd is some 5V, R is probably a couple of k\$\Omega\$ and C is in the 1uF ballpark.

Your DAC pin is an *output*. Outputs usually do not like being forced by an external voltage supply. But they are protected, and a couple of ks in series with it have limited the current to some mA, which is probably fine.

But you also hooked an earplug to it. And, while being an output, a DAC is usually not capable of directly driving such a big load, so probably the combination killed your DAC.

Comment: Thanks. when the pin fried i haven't connected the earphone. I just connected the signal and the ground of the mic input of the laptop to the DAC0 and to the ground of Arduino.

Comment: Well, that's an entirely different question. Try to do some research and come back if you are not satisfied